# Opening Userform only without flashing Excel Window

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I know the method as `Application.Visible = False`  and `Application.Screenupdating = False`

When opening the file, I want the user to see **only** the userform.

The thing is: with these two commands above, Excel appears for 1 second. Is it possible to do it without Excel blinking like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about making them not even see the excel splash screen?

Comment: you have the form opening in Sub auto_open()?....if you do and it still shows the screen I think the only way to suppress the screen is through modifying the shortcut.  I will watch this to see if anyone has another answer.

Comment: Try HTA or [this WSH VBS GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111556/2165759)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to open the excel file not with excel itself to avoid the splash. Try script to open excel file, then form will open without splash :

'save this in a text file, change extension as *.vbs*

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = false
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\yourfile.xlsm")
```

'this will open excel as invisible, so to close excel you have to insert some button *inside userform* or something like `ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges = False` or `Application.Quit`

'and of course assuming that your form is in the workbook_open in your project like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
'Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Application.EnableAnimations = False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that. But when I try to open the .vbs file, nothing happens.

Comment: you dont have to open vbs from excel! double click on the .vbs file. Have you used vbs file in the past?

Comment: I have not. But that's what I did. I tried double clicking it!

Comment: you have to change the file path and file name of yours in my above vbs code. Try `objExcel.Visible = true` to see whether excel opens or not.